# Display Location of node Title different in Teaser vs Full

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I created a custom template, `node--article.tpl.php` which renders my `field_image` field first, then shows the submission date, then displays the title and then renders the rest of the content.

This works very well in Teaser, but when I click on the node and view it in Full, the Title is rendered at the top. It is above the `field_image` instead of where it exists in the template. My template is just a slightly altered version of the Zen `node.tpl.php`. Why is the title being rendered up top instead of where it is in the template?

Here is my template:

```
<article class="node-<?php print $node->nid; ?> <?php print $classes; ?> clearfix"<?php print $attributes; ?>>

  <?php print render($content['field_image']); ?>

  <?php if ($display_submitted): ?>
    <p class="submitted">
      <!--<?php print $submitted; ?>-->
      <?php print $pubdate; ?>
    </p>
  <?php endif; ?>


  <?php if ($title_prefix || $title_suffix || $display_submitted || $unpublished || !$page && $title): ?>
    <header>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php if (!$page && $title): ?>
        <h2<?php print $title_attributes; ?>><a href="<?php print $node_url; ?>"><?php print $title; ?></a></h2>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>

      <?php if ($unpublished): ?>
        <p class="unpublished"><?php print t('Unpublished'); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
  <?php endif; ?>

  <?php
    // We hide the comments and links now so that we can render them later.
    hide($content['comments']);
    hide($content['links']);
    print render($content);
  ?>

  <?php print render($content['links']); ?>

  <?php print render($content['comments']); ?>

</article><!-- /.node -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a thought, have you tried using [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds)?

Comment: I haven't, but that looks pretty cool. Going to go check it out right now!

Comment: So, I've got installed, removed my custom template, and I configured my node type so that it should display in the right order... but it's still showing an additional Title at the top of the page. How can I disable that Title?

Comment: In manage display /admin/structure/types/manage/content_type/display y probably you need the full content and disable the title. If you want to see more about what you can do with display suite I recommend this link http://london2011.drupal.org/conference/sessions/take-full-control-your-site-layout-display-suite-drupal-7

Comment: Have you anything else which could be outputting that extra title? i.e. other modules, it's being displayed in a panel, etc. etc.

Comment: This module doesn't really answer my question, but it's so awesome that I'm accepting this as my answer.